# В Azure не работает WebSocket

Tags: nginx, docker, websocket, azure, signalr

У меня есть ASP NET CORE приложение в докере и когда я запускаю контейнер локально, сокеты работают. Когда я публикую контейнер в Azure web app for containers сокеты перестают работать и signalr переключается на longpool протокол.

Судя по ответу их отбрасывает nginx который принимает запрос до докера и должен его перенаправить на докер.
[image: error screen]
Раньше я публиковал приложение в Web app(windows) и там была галочка для включения сокетов, в Linux они включены, как я нашел в документации.

Может я должен как то настроить API для работы с nginx?

Comment: Возможно вы знаете как можно закинуть config file для nginx в Azure

Comment: Вроде как на уровне azure web app может быть отломано: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/19578. Пишите им на гитхаб. А лучше - в саппорт.

Comment: чтобы написать в суппорт нужно купить подписку :(